# JasmineJS + AngularJS: How to mock the delay inside Spy#callFake()

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery, jasmine2.0

Let's assume I have a service function that returns me the current location. And the function has callbacks to return the location. We can easily `mock` the function like as follows. But I wanted to introduce some delay (let's say 1 sec) before the `callFake()` invokes the successHandler(location).

Is there a way to achieve that?

**xxxSpec.js**

```
spyOn(LocationService, 'getLocation').and.callFake(function(successHandler, errorHandler) {

   //TODO: introduce some delay here

   const location = {...};
   successHandler(location); 
}
```

**LocationService.js**

```
function getLocation(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    let location = {...};
    successCallback(location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Introducing delay in Javascript is easily done with the setTimeout API, details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).  You haven't specified if you are using a framework such as Angular, so your code may differ slightly from what I have below.

It does not appear that you are using Observables or Promises for easier handling of asynchronous code.  Jasmine 2 does have the 'done' callback that can be useful for this.  Something like this could work:

```
it( "my test", function(done) {
    let successHandler = jasmine.createSpy();
    spyOn(LocationService, 'getLocation').and.callFake(function(successHandler, errorHandler) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            const location = {...};
            successHandler(location); 
        }, 1000); // wait for 1 second
    })

    // Now invoke the function under test
    functionUnderTest(/* location data */);

    // To test we have to wait until it's completed before expecting...
    setTimeout(function(){
        // check what you want to check in the test ...
        expect(successHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
        // Let Jasmine know the test is done.
        done();
    }, 1500); // wait for longer than one second to test results
});
```

However, it is not clear to me why adding the timeouts would be valuable to your testing.  :)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the done() construct. The problem with setTimeout() is, the control doesn't go inside spyOn -> setTimeout() body. So it never invokes the successHandler().

Comment: Do you mean the `.callFake()` is never executed?  Yes, that is the step I tried to show in my answer where I call `functionUnderTest()`.  If that function calls `LocationService.getLocation()`, then THAT is when the `.callFake()` would get executed and the `successHandler()` would be called.  You did not include this context in your question.  Perhaps you could update your question with more context - that would help give more specific answers.  :)

Comment: `.callFake()` gets called but the `successHandler(location)` inside the `setTimeout` never gets called.

Comment: Would you share the entire LocationService and .spec files?  Perhaps it would help to see what you are trying to accomplish.